# Pandas - merging dataframes conditionally on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes and I want to take one of the columns from one and create a new column in the second based on values in multiple (other) columns

First dataframe (`df1`):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cond': np.repeat([1,2], 5),
                    'point': np.tile(np.arange(1,6), 2),
                    'value1': np.random.rand(10),
                    'unused1': np.random.rand(10)})

   cond  point   unused1    value1
0     1      1  0.923699  0.103046
1     1      2  0.046528  0.188408
2     1      3  0.677052  0.481349
3     1      4  0.464000  0.807454
4     1      5  0.180575  0.962032
5     2      1  0.941624  0.437961
6     2      2  0.489738  0.026166
7     2      3  0.739453  0.109630
8     2      4  0.338997  0.415101
9     2      5  0.310235  0.660748
```

and the second (`df2`):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'cond': np.repeat([1,2], 10),
                    'point': np.tile(np.arange(1,6), 4),
                    'value2': np.random.rand(20)})

    cond  point    value2
0      1      1  0.990252
1      1      2  0.534813
2      1      3  0.407325
3      1      4  0.969288
4      1      5  0.085832
5      1      1  0.922026
6      1      2  0.567615
7      1      3  0.174402
8      1      4  0.469556
9      1      5  0.511182
10     2      1  0.219902
11     2      2  0.761498
12     2      3  0.406981
13     2      4  0.551322
14     2      5  0.727761
15     2      1  0.075048
16     2      2  0.159903
17     2      3  0.726013
18     2      4  0.848213
19     2      5  0.284404
```

`df1['value1']` contains values for each combination of `cond` and `point`.

I want to create a new column (`new_column`) in `df2` that contains values from `df1['value1']`, but the values should be the ones where `cond` and `point` are matching across the 2 dataframes.

So my desired output looks like this:

```
    cond  point    value2  new_column
0      1      1  0.990252    0.103046
1      1      2  0.534813    0.188408
2      1      3  0.407325    0.481349
3      1      4  0.969288    0.807454
4      1      5  0.085832    0.962032
5      1      1  0.922026    0.103046
6      1      2  0.567615    0.188408
7      1      3  0.174402    0.481349
8      1      4  0.469556    0.807454
9      1      5  0.511182    0.962032
10     2      1  0.219902    0.437961
11     2      2  0.761498    0.026166
12     2      3  0.406981    0.109630
13     2      4  0.551322    0.415101
14     2      5  0.727761    0.660748
15     2      1  0.075048    0.437961
16     2      2  0.159903    0.026166
17     2      3  0.726013    0.109630
18     2      4  0.848213    0.415101
19     2      5  0.284404    0.660748
```

In this example I could just use tile/repeat, but in reality `df1['value1']` doesn't fit so neatly into the other dataframe. So I just need to do it based on matching the `cond` and `point` columns

I've tried merging them, but 1) the numbers dont seem to match and 2) I dont want to bring over any unused columns from `df1`:

`df1.merge(df2, left_on=['cond', 'point'], right_on=['cond', 'point'])`

Whats the correct way to add this new column without having to iterate through the 2 dataframes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Option 1***
*For grace and speed with pure `pandas`, we can use [**`lookup`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)*
This will produce the same output as all other options, seen below.

The concept is to represent the lookup data as a 2-D array and lookup values with the indices.

```
d1 = df1.set_index(['cond', 'point']).value1.unstack()
df2.assign(new_column=d1.lookup(df2.cond, df2.point))
```

***Option 2***
*We can do the same thing with `numpy` to improve performance if the values are presented in the same way they are in `df1`.  This is very fast!*

```
a = df1.value1.values.reshape(2, -1)
df2.assign(new_column=a[df2.cond.values - 1, df2.point.values - 1])
```

***Option 3***
*The canonical answer is to use [**`merge` with the `left` parameter**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjeqeCMjd3TAhVF3WMKHbO0DzgQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.merge.html&usg=AFQjCNHVIQY-G2peKQC_B2gnCn-m_U_3Yw&sig2=t7UgvgaQw9IT9plYkIChMQ)

But we'll need to prep `df1` a bit to nail the output*

```
d1 = df1[['cond', 'point', 'value1']].rename(columns={'value1': 'new_column'})
df2.merge(d1, 'left')
```

***Option 4***
*I thought this was fun.  Build a mapping dictionary and a series to map on*
Good for small data, not so good for large data.  See timing below.

```
c1 = df1.cond.values.tolist()
p1 = df1.point.values.tolist()
v1 = df1.value1.values.tolist()
m = {(c, p): v for c, p, v in zip(c1, p1, v1)}

c2 = df2.cond.values.tolist()
p2 = df2.point.values.tolist()
i2 = df2.index.values.tolist()
s2 = pd.Series({i: (c, p) for i, c, p in zip(i2, c2, p2)})

df2.assign(new_column=s2.map(m))
```

---

***OUTPUT***

```
    cond  point    value2  new_column
0      1      1  0.990252    0.103046
1      1      2  0.534813    0.188408
2      1      3  0.407325    0.481349
3      1      4  0.969288    0.807454
4      1      5  0.085832    0.962032
5      1      1  0.922026    0.103046
6      1      2  0.567615    0.188408
7      1      3  0.174402    0.481349
8      1      4  0.469556    0.807454
9      1      5  0.511182    0.962032
10     2      1  0.219902    0.437961
11     2      2  0.761498    0.026166
12     2      3  0.406981    0.109630
13     2      4  0.551322    0.415101
14     2      5  0.727761    0.660748
15     2      1  0.075048    0.437961
16     2      2  0.159903    0.026166
17     2      3  0.726013    0.109630
18     2      4  0.848213    0.415101
19     2      5  0.284404    0.660748
```

---

***Timing***
*small data*

```
%%timeit 
a = df1.value1.values.reshape(2, -1)
df2.assign(new_column=a[df2.cond.values - 1, df2.point.values - 1])
1000 loops, best of 3: 304 µs per loop

%%timeit
d1 = df1.set_index(['cond', 'point']).value1.unstack()
df2.assign(new_column=d1.lookup(df2.cond, df2.point))
100 loops, best of 3: 1.8 ms per loop

%%timeit
c1 = df1.cond.values.tolist()
p1 = df1.point.values.tolist()
v1 = df1.value1.values.tolist()
m = {(c, p): v for c, p, v in zip(c1, p1, v1)}
​
c2 = df2.cond.values.tolist()
p2 = df2.point.values.tolist()
i2 = df2.index.values.tolist()
s2 = pd.Series({i: (c, p) for i, c, p in zip(i2, c2, p2)})
​
df2.assign(new_column=s2.map(m))
1000 loops, best of 3: 719 µs per loop

%%timeit
d1 = df1[['cond', 'point', 'value1']].rename(columns={'value1': 'new_column'})
df2.merge(d1, 'left')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.04 ms per loop

%%timeit
df = pd.merge(df2, df1.drop('unused1', axis=1), 'left')
df.rename(columns={'value1': 'new_column'})
100 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop

%%timeit
df = df2.join(df1.drop('unused1', axis=1).set_index(['cond', 'point']), on=['cond', 'point'])
df.rename(columns={'value1': 'new_column'})
100 loops, best of 3: 2.15 ms per loop
```

*large data*

```
df2 = pd.concat([df2] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

%%timeit 
a = df1.value1.values.reshape(2, -1)
df2.assign(new_column=a[df2.cond.values - 1, df2.point.values - 1])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.93 ms per loop

%%timeit
d1 = df1.set_index(['cond', 'point']).value1.unstack()
df2.assign(new_column=d1.lookup(df2.cond, df2.point))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.58 ms per loop

%%timeit
c1 = df1.cond.values.tolist()
p1 = df1.point.values.tolist()
v1 = df1.value1.values.tolist()
m = {(c, p): v for c, p, v in zip(c1, p1, v1)}
​
c2 = df2.cond.values.tolist()
p2 = df2.point.values.tolist()
i2 = df2.index.values.tolist()
s2 = pd.Series({i: (c, p) for i, c, p in zip(i2, c2, p2)})
​
df2.assign(new_column=s2.map(m))
10 loops, best of 3: 135 ms per loop

%%timeit
d1 = df1[['cond', 'point', 'value1']].rename(columns={'value1': 'new_column'})
df2.merge(d1, 'left')
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop

%%timeit
df = pd.merge(df2, df1.drop('unused1', axis=1), 'left')
df.rename(columns={'value1': 'new_column'})
10 loops, best of 3: 19.8 ms per loop

%%timeit
df = df2.join(df1.drop('unused1', axis=1).set_index(['cond', 'point']), on=['cond', 'point'])
df.rename(columns={'value1': 'new_column'})
100 loops, best of 3: 18.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael.  You as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`left join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra) and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for remove `unused1` column, last `rename` column:

Notice: Parameter `on` can be omit if in both `DataFrames` are only same columns for join. If more same column names, add `on=['cond', 'point']`.

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1.drop('unused1', axis=1), 'left')
df = df.rename(columns={'value1': 'new_column'})
print (df)
    cond  point    value2  new_column
0      1      1  0.990252    0.103046
1      1      2  0.534813    0.188408
2      1      3  0.407325    0.481349
3      1      4  0.969288    0.807454
4      1      5  0.085832    0.962032
5      1      1  0.922026    0.103046
6      1      2  0.567615    0.188408
7      1      3  0.174402    0.481349
8      1      4  0.469556    0.807454
9      1      5  0.511182    0.962032
10     2      1  0.219902    0.437961
11     2      2  0.761498    0.026166
12     2      3  0.406981    0.109630
13     2      4  0.551322    0.415101
14     2      5  0.727761    0.660748
15     2      1  0.075048    0.437961
16     2      2  0.159903    0.026166
17     2      3  0.726013    0.109630
18     2      4  0.848213    0.415101
19     2      5  0.284404    0.660748
```

Another solution with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (default [`left join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-key-columns-on-an-index)) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df2.join(df1.drop('unused1', axis=1).set_index(['cond', 'point']), on=['cond', 'point'])
df = df.rename(columns={'value1': 'new_column'})
print (df)
    cond  point    value2  new_column
0      1      1  0.990252    0.103046
1      1      2  0.534813    0.188408
2      1      3  0.407325    0.481349
3      1      4  0.969288    0.807454
4      1      5  0.085832    0.962032
5      1      1  0.922026    0.103046
6      1      2  0.567615    0.188408
7      1      3  0.174402    0.481349
8      1      4  0.469556    0.807454
9      1      5  0.511182    0.962032
10     2      1  0.219902    0.437961
11     2      2  0.761498    0.026166
12     2      3  0.406981    0.109630
13     2      4  0.551322    0.415101
14     2      5  0.727761    0.660748
15     2      1  0.075048    0.437961
16     2      2  0.159903    0.026166
17     2      3  0.726013    0.109630
18     2      4  0.848213    0.415101
19     2      5  0.284404    0.660748
```